# Google Photo API mediaItems take only first 25 item, how can I take next chunk?

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-photos-api

```py
gphoto_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
                 'photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials=creds, static_discovery=False)

all_photos = gphoto_service.mediaItems().list().execute()
all_photos = all_photos['mediaItems']
len(all_photos)
```

output:
`25`

Follow the code above, I can handle only first 25 of all photos in my Google photo.
In fact, there are thousands of photos.
I guess it take a 'chunk' of items at a time to save memory.

But how can I get 'next chunk' of photos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
gphoto_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
                 'photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials=creds, 
                 static_discovery=False)


# get first page (25 photos)
page_photos = gphoto_service.mediaItems().list().execute()
nextPageToken = page_photos['nextPageToken']


# get next page
page_photos = gphoto_service.mediaItems().list(
                    pageSize=25, pageToken=nextPageToken).execute()
nextPageToken = page_photos['nextPageToken']
```